# Unable to Debug Xamarin.Android app in VS 2022 . App closes immediately after launch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022, android-12

I need to update my Xamarin.Android app to target Android 12.
Since I couldnt download Android 12 SDK in VS2019 due to JDK11 unavailability also many says there will be some issues with JDK11 in VS2019. I have installed VS2022 17.3.1.

In VS2022, I am not able to debug the app on deployment. After deployment, the app closes immediately.

In the output it shows as below

[image]

The app deploys fine in VS2019.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the app was previously installed on the device, perhaps something is still there from the earlier install. If its an emulator, Tools / Android / Device Manager -> Factory Reset that emulator. If its an actual device, from its home page, manually uninstall the app. Restart the device.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am trying in an actual device. I did manually uninstalled the app in it and tried restarting as well @ToolmakerSteve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked these two properties in Visual Studio

1.Incremental aapt

Try choosing the below supported architectures  in advanced android options.[image]

If not try enabling it and please check.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. even after enabling those two facing the same issue

Comment: @Bhargavi Edited my answer please check again